# How can I make a phone call using the speaker in iOS?

Tags: ios, phone-call, speakerphone

I know that using the URL with `tel://` I can launch the phone app to make a phone call, but I don't know how to do the phone call with the speaker turned on.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean speaker turned on? once the call is send to the phone app you there can turn on speakers

Comment: Yes, but I need to start the phone call with the speaker already turned on.

Comment: Since the call is handled by another app, I doupt this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for that I'm afraid. The `tell://` is all the 'access' you will get as far as the phone application goes.